# Variable slots in texts coming from XML

Tags: android, locale

I'd like to include localization into my app. However, I happen to see that I need to include some vars inside a text, and sometimes they are not sorted. The easiest example would be with currency texts. In English, you could find something like `your current income is $40.00, keep it up!`, but in Spanish, it could be like `tus ingresos ascienden a 40.00$, ¡sigue así!`. In that case, currency ($) and value (40.00) are external vars which depend on every user.

The problem is that I don't know how to add slots to a text coming from a locale xml. It would be cool to have something like:

```
<string name="income">your current income is {currency}{money}, keep it up!</string>
```

However, I don't know if that is possible out of the box. Do you have any clue? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [Format String resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling)

Comment: Holy gosh, I didn't see that feature. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Currency.getInstance(Locale locale)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Currency.html#getInstance%28java.util.Locale%29) to be able to handle the differences.
To change the order you can simply use the different order in different strings, like

```
<string name="income">your current income is %1$s%2$,d, keep it up!</string>
```

or

```
<string name="income">tus ingresos ascienden a %2$,d%1$s, ¡sigue así!</string>
```

depending on the language.